# My SearchableSpinner in Android Studio does not show the result of the database in the apps

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is my homepage where after user login to him account then this system function will run. I had tried a lot of solution but still could not get the result i want. I just wanted to get data automatically when the user login and show the data from he database in the searchableSpinner.

```
    package com.example.myfyp;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

    import com.example.myfyp.Interface.IFirebaseLoadDone;
    import com.example.myfyp.Model.UserID;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, IFirebaseLoadDone {

        Button b1, b2, btnlogout;
        AudioManager am;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
        TextView newName;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        SearchableSpinner searchableSpinner;
        IFirebaseLoadDone iFirebaseLoadDone;
        FirebaseDatabase database;
        List<UserID> movies;



        ArrayList<String> arrayList;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

        private Button pass;
        private Button num;
        private Button track;
        private Button power;


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibrate);
            b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.normal);
            btnlogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
            newName = findViewById(R.id.textView);

            searchableSpinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.selectdevice);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 101);
            }

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = database.getReference("UserID");
            iFirebaseLoadDone = this;

            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                        List<UserID> movies = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot movieSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            movies.add(movieSnapShot.getValue(UserID.class));
                        }
                        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(movies);
                    }catch (DatabaseException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    try {
                        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            //addName();


            //arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Homepage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);





            am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            //1- Vibrate 2-Normal
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    am.setRingerMode(1);
                }
            });
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    am.setRingerMode(2);
                }
            });


            /*Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectdevice);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                    (this, R.array.device, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectdevice);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);*/

            pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_password);
            pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openLock();
                }

            });
            num = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_number);
            num.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openNumber();
                }

            });
            track = (Button) findViewById(R.id.track);
            track.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openTracking();
                }
            });
            power = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gps_power);
            power.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openGPSPower();
                }
            });
            btnlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    openMainActivity();
                }
            });


        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

        public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 101:
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        newName.setText(Build.DEVICE);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            newName.setText(Build.DEVICE);

        }

        /*public void addName() {
            String name = Build.DEVICE;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                Name phoneName = new Name(name);
                databaseReference.child(name).setValue(phoneName);
                Toast.makeText(this, "New name has added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        }*/





        public void openLock() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Lock.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void openNumber() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Number.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void openTracking() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tracking.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void openGPSPower() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPSPower.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void openMainActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<UserID> movieList) {
            try {
                movies = movieList;

                List<String> name_list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (UserID movie : movieList)
                    name_list.add(movie.getName());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name_list);
                searchableSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }catch(DatabaseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {

        }
    }
```

Here is where i try to put the set and get

```
package com.example.myfyp.Model;

public class UserID {
    String name;

    public UserID(){

    }

    public UserID(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information and code examples.

Comment: show whatever you tried, so we can get clarity about the problem